# Simplest way to extract a portion of a string?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, regular-expression, bioinformatics

I've got a file (bigfile.txt), one of the columns looks like this

```
NW_017095471.1  Gnomon  mRNA    108321  109565  .   +   .   ID=rna34;Parent=gene27;Dbxref=GeneID:108565285,Genbank:XM_017925071.1;Name=XM_017925071.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC108565285;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 7 Proteins%2C and 100%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 30 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=transmembrane protein 126A;transcript_id=XM_017925071.1
ID=gene27;Dbxref=GeneID:108565285;Name=LOC108565285;gbkey=Gene;gene=LOC108565285;gene_biotype=protein_coding
ID=gene28;Dbxref=GeneID:108569527;Name=LOC108569527;gbkey=Gene;gene=LOC108569527;gene_biotype=protein_coding
ID=gene78;Dbxref=GeneID:108562956;Name=LOC108562956;gbkey=Gene;gene=LOC108562956;gene_biotype=protein_coding
```

I have a separate list:

```
gene27
gene28
```

I want to take each line and grep the ID field and then return the 'LOC#' that follows "Name=".

```
gene=$line
`grep $gene";" bigfile.txt | sed -e 's/Name=
```

To return

```
LOC108565285
LOC108569527
```

How do I go about extracting just this portion?

Comment: Tried this? `awk -F'[; =]' '/ID=gene27/{print $6}' infile`

Comment: @ValentinBajrami but there are multiple genes stored in a different file.

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv don't know where you are reading that but maybe we just should wait for the OP to clarify his/her goal`

Comment: @ValentinBajrami well I am not OP, but as he wrote in question, there is a separate list, so I am assuming there are multiple vallues.

Comment: yes, exactly take the multiple values (e.g. each line in list) and search the bigfile to extract LOC. In my example I have 3 lines and I just want 2 LOC id's ... does this make sense?

Comment: @R-MASHup you have 3 lines but you want just the location of 2 lines and you put there `To return`  LOC108565285.  Please take the time to show the input and your desired output and not constantly modify the question. It isn't helping either of us

Comment: bigfile.txt is actually unwieldy, i was hoping that by just showing the single column (from bigfile.txt) that I would be able to extract LOC. the file is actually a gff3 and this is just one of the columns from which I want to extract just the LOC

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this,

```
    grep "ID=$pattern;" file | grep -o 'Name=[^;]*' | sed 's/Name=//g';
```

- `grep -o 'Name=[^;]*'` with grep the pattern starts with "Name=" and immediate ends ";"
- `sed 's/Name=//g';` just remove the pattern which is not required as per your requirement.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvwsua6gqqao6zx/ref_Nicve_v1.0_top_level.gff3?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is the 9th tab-delimited field of a [GFF file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_feature_format) (the "attributes" field), you can extract the value of the `gene` attribute corresponding to a particular `ID` attribute (read from a separate file) like this with `awk`:

```awk
BEGIN { FS = "\t" }

FNR == NR {
    # Read IDs into a hash as keys.
    ids[$1] = 1
    next
}

$3 == "gene" {
    # Split the attribute field into separate key-value pairs.
    n = split($9, keyvalues, ";")

    id = ""    # Not found a gene ID yet
    gene = ""  # No gene name to print

    # Loop over the key-value pairs, split them on the "="
    # and extract the gene name and gene ID.
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        split(keyvalues[i], attr, "=")
        if (attr[1] == "ID") {
            if (attr[2] in ids)
                id = attr[2]
            else
                next  # This line is not of interest
        }
        else if (attr[1] == "gene")
            gene = attr[2]
    }

    if (id != "" && gene != "")
        print gene
}
```

Running this on a GFF file called `file.gff` containing the given data in column 9, and with the gene ID list in `id.list`:

```
$ awk -f script.awk id.list file.gff
LOC108565285
LOC108569527
```

The list of gene IDs are read from the first file in the `FNR == NR` block in the `awk` code, while the last block is processing the attribute field of gene feature lines (only) in the second (and all later) files given on the command line.

The `awk` code assumes that the `ID` and `gene` attributes of the GFF file only contains a single value (not a comma-delimited list of values) and that the values are not quoted.

To get the output as a list of gene names and gene IDs (two columns), change the `print gene` statement to `print id, gene`.

Answer (score 0):

This needs refactoring but should do what you want:

```
while IFS=; read -r line; do grep -Fw "$line" biffile.txt; done < other_file | awk -F';' '{split($3,a,"=");print a[2]}'
```

Comment: You can use `grep -f pat.list` to grep for patterns read from a file, but your `grep` may get stuff it does not want, like a like containing `gene1000` if the pattern is `gene10` (you have the same issue in the current code).

Comment: @Kusalananda that's a good point. I guess this can be solved by passing `-w` to grep as in `..grep -Fw`

Comment: Yes, possibly, if we assume that the strings in the input list are words and don't start or end with a non-word character.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a slightly different approach. First, extract only the ID and Name fields:

```
$ sed -nE 's/.*ID=([^;]*).*Name=([^;]*).*/\1 \2/p' file1
gene27 LOC108565285
gene28 LOC108569527
gene78 LOC108562956
```

Then, filter that using the list of target IDs:

```
$ cat file2
gene27
gene28
$ sed -nE 's/.*ID=([^;]*).*Name=([^;]*).*/\1 \2/p' file1 | grep -wf file2 
gene27 LOC108565285
gene28 LOC108569527
```

Or, if you only want the `LOC....` value, and assuming you have GNU `grep`:

```
$ grep -wf file2 file1 | grep -oP 'Name=\K[^;]+'
LOC108565285
LOC108569527
```

Answer (score 0):

**Safe. Simple. Short.**

The name `bigfile.txt` suggests that we don't want to grep multiple times through it, but do it in one pass. So I prefer an attempt like @Kusalananda: Collect all gene IDs to extract and than scan once through the `bigfile`. For such a task I prefer `sed`, as you don't need do deal with programming like variables, arrays and loops, just let the tool do the work:

```
sed '/^gene[0-9]*$/{s/$/;/;H;d;};G;/ID=\(gene[0-9]*;\).*\n\1/!d;s/.*gene=\(LOC[0-9]*\);.*/\1/' genelist.txt bigfile.txt
```

And here is the explanation:

- `/^gene[0-9]*$/` is a pattern to select lines of the list: just `gene` with a number
- `{s/$/;/;H;d;}` is executed only for the lines above: `s/$/;/` appends a `;`, `H` appends this modified line to the hold space and `d` stops further processing and deletes the line
- At this point in the script we know we are in the `bigfile.txt` and the hold space is filled with all geneIDs. Now `G` appends this list to the pattern space
- The pattern `/ID=\(gene[0-9]*;\).*\n\1/` selects lines where the ID `gene[0-9]*` is repeated (the `\1` refers to the string inside the first pair of `\(\)`) after a newline, thus an ID that is present in the list
- `!d` inverts the selection and deletes, to all lines without a match get deleted
- Now for all line with a match, extract the `gene` field: `s/.*gene=\(LOC[0-9]*\);.*/\1/`

Answer (score 0):

Done by below simple script

command

```
for i in `cat file2`; do awk -v i="$i" -F ";" '$1=="ID="i{print $5}' file1| awk -F  "=" '{print $NF}'; done
```

output

```
LOC108565285
LOC108569527
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
grep "ID=gene[0-9]" bigfile.txt |  sed 's/\;/ /g' | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/Name=//g'
```

Comment: Aren't the first three pipeline elements the same as `awk -F \; '/ID=gene[0-9]/ { print $3 } ' bigfile.txt`? Also, how does the target list come into play here?